# Есть локальный сервер,как выдернуть оттуда все базы данных?

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, sql

Есть локальный сервер,как выдернуть оттуда все базы данных,их слишком много,чтобы по одному бекапить.
Есть способ чтобы сразу все сайты бекапить?

Comment: много баз или таблиц?

вообще можно так:

    mysqldump -u user -p --all-database

если хочется, чтобы каждая бд была в отдельном файле, можно посмотреть примеры скриптов [в тостере][1]

 [1]: https://toster.ru/q/14127

Comment: phpMyAdmin тоже умеет такое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот есть удобная утилита - http://sypex.net/products/dumper/downloads

Comment: так ведь в нем с каждой БД отдельно работа ведется, все сразу разве возможно экспортировать?

Comment: там можно насоздавать задач которые в дальнейшем сами будут декапить

Comment: @ICE, мой вопрос основан на исходной задаче: "их слишком много". Для пары сотен баз ваш способ будет утомительным, не находите?